# React-table grouping table column which has multiple values

Tags: react-table, react-table-v6

I am using `react-table-6`, I am trying to group my table data with pivot grouping. I have got to work to some extent, but my requirement is different. I have given my requirement in the [GitHub](https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/discussions/3036)  link.

Can you help me in grouping the data as per the requirement. Thanks in advance.